# How to make files available offline when redirecting the desktop (to network location)

Tags: folder-redirection, offline-files

I have redirected user desktops and "*My Documents*" folders to their home drives on the server.

Workstations = **Windows 7 Professional SP1**.

Server = **SBS 2003 SP2**

Now I want to make these files available if the server becomes inaccessible for any reason.

How can this be done using Offline Files?

I can't find the option anywhere on the Windows 7 clients, even when logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 3):

Redirected folders (should be) by default are setup for Offline Files unless explicitly configured otherwise. However, I would still verify it's setup correctly. But yes, offline files is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to do some testing later to see what happens if I make the server unavailable during logon. It will be interesting to see if it has already cached all this information on the workstation.